# Two methods with same name but different generic parameters

Tags: c#, .net, generics, overloading

Let's suppose I have a class `ClassA` and a class `ClassB`, which are both totally different from each other.

For example:

```
public class ClassA {}
public class ClassB {}
```

And now I define two methods:

```
public void Foo<X>(X x) where X : ClassA {}
public void Foo<Y>(Y y) where Y : ClassB {}
```

As you can see, both `Foo` methods have the same name, the same return type, and the same amount of arguments. However, each method has a different constraint. `Foo<X>` can only accept a generic parameter that extends from `ClassA`, and `Foo<Y>` can only accept a generic parameter that extends from `ClassB`.

Nevertheless, the following error is thrown by the compiler:

> Type `Testing.Program` already defines a member called `Foo` with the same parameter types

As far as I understand, each method accepts different parameter types.

What am I missing?

Comment: generic constraints are not considered a part of method signature, hence can't be used for *overloading*, Also see: [Constraints are not part of the signature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx)

Comment: That's... dissapointing to hear :( Why are they not taken into account?

Comment: You can always get around this with type-checking within the generic method itself.  Or renaming the generic method in a way that differentiates the two methods based on the generic constraints (`FooA<X>`)